# C# string interpolation - is it possible to reflect internal intermediate structure?

Tags: c#, c#-6.0

Been using Dapper lately, so of course there is lots of code like:

```
var id = 123;
var s = "hola";
conn.Execute("update foo set bar = @a where id = @b", new { a = s, b = id })
```

This was also my first time with C# 6.0, so I've noticed similarity between the above and string interpolation:

```
$"update foo set bar = {s} where id = {id}"
```

However. this just works on plain strings, without any knowledge of parameters, escaping and so on. Would it be somehow possible to reflect on the intermediate structure generated by the compiler and then use it to properly set up the parameters? So, instead of resulting string, one could obtain something something that contains the string with holes, and the array of objects. Feels to me one could do quite a lot of things with such data.

Comment: *Would it be somehow possible to reflect on the intermediate structure generated by the compiler and then use it to properly set up the parameters* I don't comprehend what you mean here...

Comment: And when would you like to do this analysis? At compile time (just after compile time)? At runtime?

Comment: At runtime. In a nutshell, instead of getting readymade string from such interpolation, I'd like to get that structure compiler uses to convert it to (if I'm correct) string.Format calls: a string with holes and the array of objects. Seems to me it could be quite useful

Comment: Look [here](http://goo.gl/Gk2yRB) at how the `$"..."` is "implemented"... It is replaced by the compiler to a `String.Format()`

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. If you want to get the representation of the `string.Format` that the compiler emits, you could try writing a Roslyn extension that does that. Not sure what use that would be to production code though.

Comment: Note that it is possible to create a class that implements the `IFormattable` interface... But still you'll get the pre-formatted string and an array of parameters. You'll have to parse the string yourself...

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

```
public static class DbExtensions
{
    public static IDbCommand CreateCommand(this IDbConnection connection, FormattableString commandText)
    {
        var command = connection.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        if (commandText.ArgumentCount > 0)
        {
            var commandTextArguments = new string[commandText.ArgumentCount];
            for (var i = 0; i < commandText.ArgumentCount; i++)
            {
                commandTextArguments[i] = "@p" + i.ToString();
                command.AddParameter(commandTextArguments[i], commandText.GetArgument(i));
            }

            command.CommandText = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, commandText.Format, commandTextArguments);
        }
        else
        {
            command.CommandText = commandText.Format;
        }

        return command;
    }
}
```

Comment: But my question was in fact how to obtain FormattableString. But your snippet helped me to google out more info, and I've found this: https://gist.github.com/svick/e5b30f73146a501cc64f. It does exactly what I wanted, nice!